# Bazel external dependency rebuilt unnecessarily in rule used as a tool from within another rule

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am working on a set of [Bazel rules](https://github.com/agoessling/rules_symbiyosys) where one [test rule](https://github.com/agoessling/rules_symbiyosys/blob/master/symbiyosys/defs.bzl#L63) is also executed as a tool from within another [executable rule](https://github.com/agoessling/rules_symbiyosys/blob/master/symbiyosys/defs.bzl#L148).  The test rule depends on an [external tool](https://github.com/agoessling/rules_symbiyosys/blob/master/symbiyosys/tools/BUILD#L4) which is built by [rules_foreign_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc).

```
symbiyosys_test = rule(
    implementation = _symbiyosys_test_impl,
    doc = "Formal verification of (System) Verilog.",
    attrs = {
        ...,
        "_yosys_toolchain": attr.label(
            doc = "Yosys toolchain.",
            default = Label("@rules_symbiyosys//symbiyosys/tools:yosys"),
        ),
        "_yices_toolchain": attr.label(
            doc = "Yices toolchain.",
            default = Label("@rules_symbiyosys//symbiyosys/tools:yices"),
        ),
    },
    test = True,
)

symbiyosys_trace = rule(
    implementation = _symbiyosys_trace_impl,
    doc = "View VCD trace from Symbiyosys.",
    attrs = {
        "test": attr.label(
            doc = "Symbiyosys test target to produce VCD file.",
            mandatory = True,
            executable = True,
            cfg = "exec",
        ),
        ...,
    },
    executable = True,
)
```

With a virgin Bazel cache, when an instance of the test rule is run with `bazel test //examples:counter_fail` the external tool is built.  The external tool is also built when an instance of the executable rule (which utilizes the test rule) is run with `bazel run //examples:counter_fail_trace`.  Once the external tool has been built in these two contexts, subsequent tests or runs use the cached outputs.

Building the external tool twice seems unnecessary as both the test and executable rule have the same configuration ("exec").  I have a hunch that this may have to do with `bazel test` and `bazel run` invoking different command line options causing the cache to miss on the external dependency.

My question is primarily what is causing this rebuild and how do I get rid of it?  And short of answering that, what are some techniques to dig into what is causing this rebuild?  I have tried some basic Bazel queries, but haven't had much luck.

**EDIT**

I still haven't cracked this one.  I do suspect a subtle difference between `bazel test` and `bazel run` but unfortunately there is limited information about how specifically the two differ in the documentation.